# Some notation in Orbital stability of standing waves for some nonlinear Schrödinger equations

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Picture below are from [**Orbital stability of standing waves for some nonlinear Schrödinger equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01403504).

First, what is the means of the two red line ?

Besides, in the definition of $I_\lambda^\infty$, seemly, the $\lambda$ is unnecessary .

> [image]
>   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $]a,b[$ is here meant to be the same thing as the open interval $(a,b)$.  I believe this notation is meant to refer to the fact that $(a,b) = \{ (-\infty,a] \cup [b,\infty)\}^C$.

As for the $I_\lambda$ definition, it's hard to say for sure from just the two small pictures you've posted.  For instance, it's not clear what $A$ and $E$ are and if / how they depends on any parameters.  If I had to guess, though, I would say that there is a typo in the definition and the $\mu$ is supposed to be a $\lambda$, i.e. the infimum is taken over $u$ such that $|u|_{L^2}^2 = \lambda$.